# How to set OpenIdConnect Client Authentication Method (from a config as a parameter) in C# using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, openid-connect

Given an OIDC implementation supporting the major id providers like Google, Okta, Azure, OneLogin etc. but now I run into a problem. A client of ours wants to use their own custom IDP, which only supports `client_secret_basic` as a Client Authentication method as their IDP says in their meta json:

```
"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
"client_secret_basic"
],
```

As I learned, OIDC standard defines the followings:
"client_secret_basic","client_secret_post","client_secret_jwt","private_key_jwt","none"

But seemingly, we "do not support" client_secret_basic as they got this error:

```
 Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'client authentication failed', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
```

which I learned to indicate a problem with client authentication (method). Also, when I tried to switch the Authentication Method setting for OneLogin IDP in our dev environment as you see here

[image]

I got the same error message as our partner.

When browsing options for setting up `AuthenticationBuilder` I found something called `AuthenticationMethod`:

```
// ...
            foreach (var idp in idProviders)
            {
                builder.AddOpenIdConnect(idp.Name, idp.DisplayName, options =>
                  {
                      mapper.Map(idp.Options, options);
                      options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                      options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;
                      options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet; // test line added ("hardcoded") by me
// ...
```

It is an enum:

```
public enum OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior
{
    RedirectGet = 0,
    FormPost = 1
}
```

Its name AuthenticationMethod seems to be similar, albeit I don't think it's the correct option as

1. it doesn't solve the problem
2. it has only 2 options
3. the values of enum don't match exactly the names in the OIDC standard (like `client_secret_basic`)
4. its default already RedirectGet:
   public OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior AuthenticationMethod { get; set; } = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
   whereas OneLogin works with `POST` but not with `GET`.

So, how can I change the client authentication method (and still keep supporting all standard IDPs - hence the config parameter)?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Microsoft does not support the "client_secret_basic" authentication method. At least OneLogin says so:
https://developers.onelogin.com/blog/how-to-use-openid-connect-authentication-with-dotnet-core :
"Dotnet OpenId Connect libraries do not support the Basic method of authentication."